# Applying Kiss FFT on audio samples and getting NaN output?

Tags: c++, audio, kissfft

The title explains my problem.

What I am trying to do is quite simple:

- Load MP3 track (via libmpg123)
- Read samples
- Apply Kiss FFT on the samples

What I have tried so far

```
inline float scale(kiss_fft_scalar val)
{
    int g = 0;
    return val < 0 ? val*(1/32768.0f ) : val*(1/32767.0f);
}

void main()
{
    mpg123_handle *m = NULL;
    int  channels = 0, encoding = 0;
    long rate = 0;
    int err = MPG123_OK;

    err = mpg123_init();        
    m = mpg123_new(NULL, &err);
    mpg123_open(m, "L:\\audio-io\\audio-analysis\\samples\\zero.mp3");
    mpg123_getformat(m, &rate, &channels, &encoding);

    err = mpg123_format_none(m);
    err = mpg123_format(m, rate, channels, encoding);

    // Get 2048 samples
    const int TIME = 2048;

    // 16-bit integer encoded in bytes, hence x2 size
    unsigned char* buffer = new unsigned char[TIME*2];
    size_t done = 0;
    err = mpg123_read(m, buffer, TIME*2, &done);

    short* samples = new short[done/2];
    int index = 0;

    // Iterate 2 bytes at a time
    for (int i = 0; i < done; i += 2)
    {
        unsigned char first = buffer[i];
        unsigned char second = buffer[i + 1];
        samples[index++] = (first | (second << 8));
    }

    // Array to store the calculated data
    int speclen = TIME / 2 + 1;
    float* output = new float[speclen];

    kiss_fftr_cfg config;
    kiss_fft_cpx* spectrum;

    config = kiss_fftr_alloc(TIME, 0, NULL, NULL);
    spectrum = (kiss_fft_cpx*) malloc(sizeof(kiss_fft_cpx) * TIME);

    // Right here...
    kiss_fftr(config, (kiss_fft_scalar*) samples, spectrum);

    for (int i = 0; i < speclen; i++)
    {
        float re = scale(spectrum[i].r) * TIME;
        float im = scale(spectrum[i].i) * TIME;

        output[i] = sqrtf(re*re + im*im);
    }

    return;
}
```

The problem occurs at this line `kiss_fftr(config, (kiss_fft_scalar*) samples, spectrum);`
Where `samples` contains the audio samples (16 bit), and `spectrum` is suppose to hold the output data.

After the function completes, here is what's happening in the debugger window.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5Wtd.png]

Can someone give me a simple example of how to apply Kiss FFT functions on audio (16 bit encoded) samples?

Comment: Isn't there any documentation or sample usage code in KissFFT???

Comment: It wasn't mine, but it, perhaps, reflected the apparent lack of effort on your side?

Comment: The attached sample code shows what I have tried. I have been unable to find any similar case to what I am experiencing on Google. The code, I believe, is more or less the how it should be done. I'm trying to figure out why I am getting NaN values.

Comment: You could try using simple signals first: all zeroes, all ones, a sinewave, etc to see that FFT itself is working. I can't believe there isn't enough sample code or documentation to figure out how the KissFFT routines should be used in the simplest cases like these. Once you've got that working, you can start playing with mp3 data. Come on.

Comment: Yes, I have attempted that as well. (In the sample code, zero.mp3 is a file filled with zero frequencies) Believe it or not, the same result (NaN) still occurs.

Comment: Hello i m struglling with the same problem.. I have tested with the all zeros and ones it gives perfect o/p. bt when i try live audio it gives me wrong o/p...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to find the bug(s) in your code. My test code appears to work just fine.

Complex-valued forward FFT with floats:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "kiss_fft.h"

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979324
#endif

#define N 16

void TestFft(const char* title, const kiss_fft_cpx in[N], kiss_fft_cpx out[N])
{
  kiss_fft_cfg cfg;

  printf("%s\n", title);

  if ((cfg = kiss_fft_alloc(N, 0/*is_inverse_fft*/, NULL, NULL)) != NULL)
  {
    size_t i;

    kiss_fft(cfg, in, out);
    free(cfg);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
      printf(" in[%2zu] = %+f , %+f    "
             "out[%2zu] = %+f , %+f\n",
             i, in[i].r, in[i].i,
             i, out[i].r, out[i].i);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("not enough memory?\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  kiss_fft_cpx in[N], out[N];
  size_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    in[i].r = in[i].i = 0;
  TestFft("Zeroes (complex)", in, out);

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    in[i].r = 1, in[i].i = 0;
  TestFft("Ones (complex)", in, out);

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    in[i].r = sin(2 * M_PI * 4 * i / N), in[i].i = 0;
  TestFft("SineWave (complex)", in, out);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Zeroes (complex)
 in[ 0] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 0] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 1] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 1] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 2] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 2] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 3] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 3] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 4] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 4] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 5] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 5] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 6] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 6] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 7] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 7] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 8] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 8] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 9] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 9] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[10] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[10] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[11] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[11] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[12] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[12] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[13] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[13] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[14] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[14] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[15] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[15] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
Ones (complex)
 in[ 0] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 0] = +16.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 1] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 1] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 2] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 2] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 3] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 3] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 4] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 4] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 5] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 5] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 6] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 6] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 7] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 7] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 8] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 8] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 9] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 9] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[10] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[10] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[11] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[11] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[12] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[12] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[13] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[13] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[14] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[14] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[15] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[15] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
SineWave (complex)
 in[ 0] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 0] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 1] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 1] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 2] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 2] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 3] = -1.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 3] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 4] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 4] = +0.000000 , -8.000000
 in[ 5] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 5] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 6] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 6] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 7] = -1.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 7] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 8] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 8] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 9] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[ 9] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[10] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[10] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[11] = -1.000000 , +0.000000    out[11] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[12] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[12] = +0.000000 , +8.000000
 in[13] = +1.000000 , +0.000000    out[13] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[14] = +0.000000 , +0.000000    out[14] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[15] = -1.000000 , +0.000000    out[15] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
```

Real-valued forward FFT with floats:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "kiss_fftr.h"

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979324
#endif

#define N 16

void TestFftReal(const char* title, const kiss_fft_scalar in[N], kiss_fft_cpx out[N / 2 + 1])
{
  kiss_fftr_cfg cfg;

  printf("%s\n", title);

  if ((cfg = kiss_fftr_alloc(N, 0/*is_inverse_fft*/, NULL, NULL)) != NULL)
  {
    size_t i;

    kiss_fftr(cfg, in, out);
    free(cfg);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      printf(" in[%2zu] = %+f    ",
             i, in[i]);
      if (i < N / 2 + 1)
        printf("out[%2zu] = %+f , %+f",
               i, out[i].r, out[i].i);
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    printf("not enough memory?\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  kiss_fft_scalar in[N];
  kiss_fft_cpx out[N / 2 + 1];
  size_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    in[i] = 0;
  TestFftReal("Zeroes (real)", in, out);

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    in[i] = 1;
  TestFftReal("Ones (real)", in, out);

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    in[i] = sin(2 * M_PI * 4 * i / N);
  TestFftReal("SineWave (real)", in, out);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Zeroes (real)
 in[ 0] = +0.000000    out[ 0] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 1] = +0.000000    out[ 1] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 2] = +0.000000    out[ 2] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 3] = +0.000000    out[ 3] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 4] = +0.000000    out[ 4] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 5] = +0.000000    out[ 5] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 6] = +0.000000    out[ 6] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 7] = +0.000000    out[ 7] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 8] = +0.000000    out[ 8] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 9] = +0.000000    
 in[10] = +0.000000    
 in[11] = +0.000000    
 in[12] = +0.000000    
 in[13] = +0.000000    
 in[14] = +0.000000    
 in[15] = +0.000000    
Ones (real)
 in[ 0] = +1.000000    out[ 0] = +16.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 1] = +1.000000    out[ 1] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 2] = +1.000000    out[ 2] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 3] = +1.000000    out[ 3] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 4] = +1.000000    out[ 4] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 5] = +1.000000    out[ 5] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 6] = +1.000000    out[ 6] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 7] = +1.000000    out[ 7] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 8] = +1.000000    out[ 8] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 9] = +1.000000    
 in[10] = +1.000000    
 in[11] = +1.000000    
 in[12] = +1.000000    
 in[13] = +1.000000    
 in[14] = +1.000000    
 in[15] = +1.000000    
SineWave (real)
 in[ 0] = +0.000000    out[ 0] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 1] = +1.000000    out[ 1] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 2] = +0.000000    out[ 2] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 3] = -1.000000    out[ 3] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 4] = +0.000000    out[ 4] = +0.000000 , -8.000000
 in[ 5] = +1.000000    out[ 5] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 6] = +0.000000    out[ 6] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 7] = -1.000000    out[ 7] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 8] = +0.000000    out[ 8] = +0.000000 , +0.000000
 in[ 9] = +1.000000    
 in[10] = +0.000000    
 in[11] = -1.000000    
 in[12] = +0.000000    
 in[13] = +1.000000    
 in[14] = +0.000000    
 in[15] = -1.000000
```

Comment: Hello i m struglling with the same problem.. I have tested with the all zeros and ones it gives perfect o/p. bt when i try live audio it gives me wrong o/p...

Comment: @Sunnyshah Either you're feeding it the wrong data or you're expecting the wrong result from it. As long as InverseFFT(FFT(signal))=signal, the problem is definitely in your code and not in the FFT. If, OTOH, InverseFFT(FFT(signal))≠signal, it's still very likely that you're not using the (I)FFT routines properly. I'm afraid, you'll have to debug your code.

Comment: Thanks i got my problem i was feeding wrong data.. but now i m strulling with another problem please look at that my code [Peak Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934097/how-can-i-calculate-the-peak-using-kissfft)

Answer (score 4):

When I first started looking at this answer I kept wondering why the -8.0 was turning up in the imaginary component rather than the real part. It was whilst re-reading a printed article on FFT's that I realised I'd been thinking about magnitude.

So I tweaked the answer in the Complex code to change the printf as follows

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    printf(" in[%02i]=%+f, %+f  out[%02i]=%+f, %+f M[%02i]=%+f\n",
         i, in[i].r, in[i].i,
         i, out[i].r, out[i].i,
         i, sqrt((out[i].r * out[i].r) + (out[i].i * out[i].i)));
```

Which produces an answer showing the magnitude as well.

```
...
SineWave (complex)
 in[00]=+0.000000, +0.000000  out[00]=+0.000000, +0.000000 M[00]=+0.000000
 in[01]=+1.000000, +0.000000  out[01]=+0.000000, +0.000000 M[01]=+0.000000
 in[02]=+0.000000, +0.000000  out[02]=+0.000000, +0.000000 M[02]=+0.000000
 in[03]=-1.000000, +0.000000  out[03]=+0.000000, +0.000000 M[03]=+0.000000
 in[04]=-0.000000, +0.000000  out[04]=-0.000000, -8.000000 M[04]=+8.000000
 in[05]=+1.000000, +0.000000  out[05]=+0.000000, -0.000000 M[05]=+0.000000
 in[06]=+0.000000, +0.000000  out[06]=+0.000000, -0.000000 M[06]=+0.000000
 in[07]=-1.000000, +0.000000  out[07]=+0.000000, -0.000000 M[07]=+0.000000
 in[08]=-0.000000, +0.000000  out[08]=+0.000000, +0.000000 M[08]=+0.000000
 in[09]=+1.000000, +0.000000  out[09]=+0.000000, +0.000000 M[09]=+0.000000
 in[10]=+0.000000, +0.000000  out[10]=+0.000000, +0.000000 M[10]=+0.000000
 in[11]=-1.000000, +0.000000  out[11]=+0.000000, +0.000000 M[11]=+0.000000
 in[12]=-0.000000, +0.000000  out[12]=-0.000000, +8.000000 M[12]=+8.000000
 in[13]=+1.000000, +0.000000  out[13]=+0.000000, -0.000000 M[13]=+0.000000
 in[14]=+0.000000, +0.000000  out[14]=+0.000000, -0.000000 M[14]=+0.000000
 in[15]=-1.000000, +0.000000  out[15]=+0.000000, -0.000000 M[15]=+0.000000
```

I also played around changing the frequency in the for loop that generates the sine wave.

```
float freq;
...
freq = 6.0;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    in[i].r = sin(2 * M_PI * freq * i / N), in[i].i = 0;
```

And so long as I stayed with multiples of 1.0 and under the Nyquist frequency 16/2 = 8 the result shifted from bin to bin quite nicely. Of course setting the frequency to fractional values sees its magnitude spread across the bins and without applying a windowing function we get leakage. If you are still struggling with FFT's like I am play around with code like this where you can see all of the results on a single screen for a while and things start to become clearer.

Finally a vote of thanks to Alexey for the answer it helped me get started with Kiss FFT.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
in[i].r = sin(2 * M_PI * freq * (i / N*1.00)), in[i].i = 0;
```

Comment: It would help if you could explain why this solves the issue.

Comment: both of variables "i" and "N" are int`s and result will be the same. If you change the code to add multiplication data in the array should be correct.